error TS2304: Cannot find name 'localStorage' on Angular app build in NX
I'm not able to run the 'build' command on an Angular app inside a NX workspace anymore. An error occurs while NX is building a dependent library that accesses 'localStorage' on the dom:
Executing task: npx nx run my-app:build --configuration=production 
  
   ×  1/20 dependent project tasks failed (see below)
   √  19/20 dependent project tasks succeeded [19 read from cache]

libs\my-lib\src\example-file.ts:43:5 error TS2304: Cannot find name 'localStorage'.

When I build the library that causes the issue alone (Without the Angular App), i don't get any error:
Executing task: npx nx run my-lib:build 

   √  8/8 dependent project tasks succeeded [8 read from cache]

 NX   Successfully ran target build for project my-lib and 8 tasks it depends on (1s)

The issue occurs both with 'production' and 'development' builds.
The issue only occurs with the 'build' command, everything works well with the 'serve' command.
I tried adding "lib": ["es2022", "dom"] on tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json of the app to allow access to the DOM. It doesn't solve the issue.
If I add "lib": ["es2022"] (without DOM) on tsconfig.lib.json of the library and build the library alone, the error occurs.
I tried adding "ssr": false and "prerender": false to project.json file of the angular app, as I have seen that some people get the issue while trying to access localStorage on Server Side Rendering.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Angular version: 18.2.10
NX version: 20.0.7
Typescript version: 5.5.4
project.json of the angular app:
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "projectType": "application",
  "prefix": "app",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/my-app/src",
  "tags": [],
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "verbose": true,
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/my-app",
        "index": "apps/my-app/src/index.html",
        "browser": "apps/my-app/src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": [], 
        "tsConfig": "apps/my-app/tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": [
          "apps/my-app/src/favicon.ico",
          "apps/my-app/src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "apps/my-app/src/styles.scss",
          {
            "input": "apps/my-app/src/assets/styles/themes/dark-cyan-theme.scss",
            "bundleName": "dark-cyan-theme",
            "inject": false
          },
          {
            "input": "apps/my-app/src/assets/styles/themes/dark-deep-purple-theme.scss",
            "bundleName": "dark-deep-purple-theme",
            "inject": false
          },
          {
            "input": "apps/my-app/src/assets/styles/themes/dark-grey-theme.scss",
            "bundleName": "dark-grey-theme",
            "inject": false
          },
          {
            "input": "apps/my-app/src/assets/styles/themes/dark-light-green-theme.scss",
            "bundleName": "dark-light-green-theme",
            "inject": false
          },
          {
            "input": "apps/my-app/src/assets/styles/themes/dark-pink-theme.scss",
            "bundleName": "dark-pink-theme",
            "inject": false
          },
          {
            "input": "apps/my-app/src/assets/styles/themes/dark-yellow-theme.scss",
            "bundleName": "dark-yellow-theme",
            "inject": false
          },
          {
            "input": "apps/my-app/src/assets/styles/themes/light-amber-theme.scss",
            "bundleName": "light-amber-theme",
            "inject": false
          },
          {
            "input": "apps/my-app/src/assets/styles/themes/light-blue-gray-theme.scss",
            "bundleName": "light-blue-gray-theme",
            "inject": false
          },
          {
            "input": "apps/my-app/src/assets/styles/themes/light-blue-theme.scss",
            "bundleName": "light-blue-theme",
            "inject": false
          },
          {
            "input": "apps/my-app/src/assets/styles/themes/light-indigo-theme.scss",
            "bundleName": "light-indigo-theme",
            "inject": false
          },
          {
            "input": "apps/my-app/src/assets/styles/themes/light-pink-theme.scss",
            "bundleName": "light-pink-theme",
            "inject": false
          },
          {
            "input": "apps/my-app/src/assets/styles/themes/light-teal-theme.scss",
            "bundleName": "light-teal-theme",
            "inject": false
          }
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "2mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "ssr": false,
          "prerender": false 
        },
        "development": {
          "optimization": false,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "ssr": false,
          "prerender": false 
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "buildTarget": "my-app:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
          "buildTarget": "my-app:build:development"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "my-app:build"
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "executor": "@nx/eslint:lint"
    },
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nx/jest:jest",
      "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/coverage/{projectRoot}"],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "apps/my-app/jest.config.ts"
      }
    }
  }
}


is "lib": ["es2022", "dom"]  added to the tsconfig of the angular app also?

@NarenMurali Yes, it tried adding it to the compiler options of tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json on the angular app

please add your project.json of angular app

I added it, only replacing the real app name with 'my-app'

I got a working solution, I replaced :
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      ...
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      ...
    },
  },

with:
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/angular:application",
      ...
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@nx/angular:dev-server",
      ...
    },
  },

in the project.json of the angular app

Strangely started seeing the same issue after updating Nx to 20.x.
To me it feels off that the solution is to change the executors.

Btw, same version, 20.0.7. Might really be a problem with Nx core.

Turns out I had a rogue import of a class from a UI (and thus DOM-enabled) library, in a library where the DOM isn't in the libs arrays. Had to look at the Nx graph to find it out.
